# Screw based Jacobian

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, jacobian, screw-theory

I am working on kinematics of 5-DOF robot. I already derived geometric Jacobian for position and orientation control.

But for singularity analysis, I require a simplified jacobian. And that can be obtained on base of [screw theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory) called [**Screw Based Jacobian.**](http://mechanismsrobotics.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=1451074)

But I am not able to find the method to obtain screw based jacobian matrix; which completely explain the method to derive screw based jacobian.

Any advice on where I can get it? Please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

The geometric Jacobian provides all the information you need for singularity or manipulability analysis.  Linearly dependent columns correspond to joints with parallel axes.  More information about Jacobians for under-actuated manipulators (as is your case) can be found in my book Robotics, Vision & Control" section 8.4.1.

For information about computing the "screw based Jacobian" check out the book Modern Robotics by Park&Lynch.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Peter Corke's answer, there's also a [Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/modernrobotics-course2?specialization=modernrobotics) by Kevin Lynch which uses the Modern Robotics book as a reference and explains how to derive the screw based Jacobian. The Jacobian can be either with respect to the "space frame" (frame attached to base of the manipulator) or the "body frame" (frame attached to the end-effector). Here's a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbI8HN3imtQ) from that course that explains the derivation.